# What does "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES will only work for the views or objects that don't have permissions explicitly set." mean?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions

I was reading below mentioned blog which is about **Built-in permissions in DRF** 
Source: https://testdriven.io/blog/built-in-permission-classes-drf/


In this blog there is statement: 
`DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES will only work for the views or objects that don't have permissions explicitly set.`

`You don't necessarily need to use built-in classes here. You can use your own custom classes as well.`


**Question**: What does `set permissions explicitly` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means telling django which permission class it should use for this specific view

in this example I'm telling django to use the `IsAuthenticated` class rather
than using the default permissions class which is defined in the settings.py file

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```